# C# code always returns false from DateTime.TryParseExact method

Tags: c#, datetime

I am working on a C# application. I have below code to validate the date:

```
private DateTime? ParseUserInputDate(string providedDate)
{
      DateTime validDate;
      var dateFormatIsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
        providedDate,
        Constants.DateFormats.UserInput,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out validDate);
      return dateFormatIsValid ? validDate : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

When I pass "2/09/2019 12:00:00 AM" as `providedDate` and UserInput format is "d/M/yyyy", it returns always false. Can someone help me to figure out this issue?

Comment: use "d/MM/yyyy", the month has two digits, not only one.

Comment: oh, and the format is missing the time part, too.

Comment: Thanks So I should add format as  public const string UserTimeDisplayFormatWithTime = "d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";?

Comment: well, that returns true on my machine :)

Comment: If you use `TryParseExact`, then it means you want a stricter parsing that `TryParse`. If data is computer generated you might want to be strict as the formatting is well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format and input are completely different. if you pass "2/09/2019 12:00:00 AM", then change the format to  "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"

```
    Private static DateTime? ParseUserInputDate(string providedDate)
    {
        DateTime validDate;
        string[] formats = { "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "d/M/yyyy" };
        var dateFormatIsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
          providedDate,
          formats,
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
          DateTimeStyles.None,
          out validDate);
        return dateFormatIsValid ? validDate : (DateTime?)null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse *time*, you have to mention *time part* in the pattern; if you have to use *several* patterns (say, with and without date) you can put them into one `TryParseExact`:

```
private DateTime? ParseUserInputDate(string providedDate) {
  // we can simplify the code with a help of out var
  return DateTime.TryParseExact(providedDate,
                                new string[] {
                                  "d/M/yyyy",            // Try date first
                                  "d/M/yyyy h:m:s tt",   // if fails try date and time
                                },
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.None,
                                out var validDate)
    ? validDate
    : (DateTime?) null;
}

...

// Date and Time
Console.WriteLine(ParseUserInputDate("2/09/2019 12:00:00 AM")
  .Value
  .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

// Date only
Console.WriteLine(ParseUserInputDate("2/09/2019")
 .Value
 .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
02.09.2019 00:00:00
02.09.2019 00:00:00
```